# When is the zero weight space of an irreducible $\frak{sl}_{n+1}$-module non-trivial?

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Take the complex semisimple Lie algebra $\frak{sl}_{n+1}$, with space of dominant integral weights $P(\frak{sl}_{n+1})$. For $V(\lambda)$ the irreducible representation corresponding to $\lambda \in P(\frak{sl}_{n+1})$, for which $\lambda$'s does it happen that the degree zero weight space of $V(\lambda)$ is non-trivial? I am also interested in this question for the other series.

Comment: This happens exactly when lambda belongs to the coroot lattice. (Incidentally my phone keeps autocorrecting “coroot” to “corporate.”)

Comment: Based on the last couple questions you’ve asked, I think you could benefit from reading a standard treatment of the theory of simple Lie algebras and their representations, like Bourbaki or Humphreys.

Comment: @Sam Hopkins: In general, it is the root lattice, not the coroot lattice.

Comment: @FriedrichKnop: whoops, you are of course right. (It is easy to get these things mixed up, which is why it is nice to go back to a standard source like Bourbaki...)